# what package I should import to use DataProvider class

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I need to use `DataProvider` class and i cannot find the package that contains it. In all examples I saw they use `fl.data`, but I'm using flex builder sdk 3.4 beta and it doesn't have such a package. Any clue?

Thanks,

Nava

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fl.data.DataProvider` is a Flash authoring tool specific class and cannot be imported to a flex project. Check out [ArrayCollection](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/collections/ArrayCollection.html) or [XMLListCollection](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/collections/XMLListCollection.html) for flex.

As far as Adobe's classes are concerned, packages starting with

- `fl.*` are CS3/4 only.
- `mx.*` are Flex/AIR only.
- `flash.*` are available everywhere.

Comment: If you have Flash Pro, and you want to use the fl.* components in Flash Builder, you can place all the components in your library and then export them in a SWC. If you only have Flash Builder, then they're not available, like you said.