# How to add Actionscript 3 fl.controls (UIScrollBar) on Linux

Tags: linux, flash, actionscript-3

How would one go about adding fl.controls.* to AS3 projects developed under Linux?

Apparently it is not part of Flex 3SDK for Linux (which is what I am using to compile) or maybe it is and I am not importing it correctly..I downloaded this SDK last March, maybe time for update?

Looking at [Adobe Official Docs](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/controls/package-detail.html) for fl.controls does not mention that this library is somehow restricted.

In particular, I was looking for fl.controls.UIScrollBar type of functionality

I am using [MiniBuilder](http://code.google.com/p/minibuilder/) to edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packages starting with `fl.*` are part of (and only available in) the Flash authoring tool (Adobe CS3/4) and cannot be imported to Flex projects. [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154966/what-package-i-should-import-to-use-dataprovider-class/2155044#2155044)